# NextJS v10 + i18n - Rewrite folder name on different languages

Tags: internationalization, next.js

I have a multi-language website and I am trying to translate a folder to be different on each language.

My folder structure looks like the this:

```
pages/kennis/index.tsx
```

I can't figure out how to translate the "kennis" folder to be different on each language. The documentation of NextJS (https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/i18n-routing#domain-routing) does not say anything about this.

Let's say for NL I want "/kennis" and for EN I want "/en/knowledge".

Does someone know a solution for this?

Comment: Currently, Next.js does not support this out-of-the-box. You'll need to build your own solution, or look for third-party options.

Comment: Did you figure out how to do this? I am trying to accomplish something similar

Answer (score 0):

You can check this package:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/next-translate-routes

just add a file _routes.json, example:

```
// `/pages/_routes.json`
{
  "kennis": {
    "es": "mas",
    "pt": "mais"
  }
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved by providing an example of the solution and how it helps the OP.

Comment: They have a example there https://github.com/hozana/next-translate-routes/tree/master/example,  but I added anyway, thanks